# Router: Setting up OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openvpn, modem

I have a TP-Link Archer A6 router  and set up an OpenVPN server on it, but when I try to connect to it using OpenVPN Connect on Android, it always times out:

- `traceroute` shows a loop inside my ISP's servers; how can I fix this? [image: TTL loop]

**Router settings:**

- OpenVPN (I've generated OpenVPN certificates): [image: OpenVPN Settings Screenshot]
- DDNS: [image: DDNS Screenshot]
- ISP provided modem is a ZTE GPON660 (Modem + WiFi Router) ([manual](https://fccid.io/Q78-ZXHNF660/Users-Manual/Users-Manual-1606423)) and does not have a Bridge setting, so I set up a DMZ to forward to my router's IP Address: [image: DMZ Settings Screenshot]

  - I bound the DMZ to the router via its MAC: [image: Binding Screenshot].
- `client.ovpn`:

  ```xml
  client
  dev tun
  proto udp
  remote my.ddns.com 1194

  float
  nobind
  comp-lzo adaptive

  cipher AES-128-CBC
  remote-cert-tls server

  persist-key
  psersist-tun
  <ca>
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  <<certificate key>>
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  </ca>
  <cert
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  <<certificate key>>
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  </cert>
  <key>
  -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
  <<certificate key>>
  -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
  </key>
  ```

Comment: It is very odd for a GPON modem to not have bridge mode... Can you show the ZTE modem/router's status page, where it shows its WAN IP address? (The loop makes me think of CGNAT.)

Comment: @user1686 https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sEhg.png

Comment: That definitely looks like CGNAT. Note how it doesn't show "your" WAN IP address (202.83.44.75) anywhere -- it only shows a private-use address.

Comment: Um... I don't know what a CGNAT is. Can you please elaborate, or preferably give an answer...?

Comment: CGNAT is carrier grade NAT, and it happens when your ISP shares a bunch if IP addresses between an even bugger buch of users. Its not nice, but then again, there is not a lot of IPv4 space unallocated...

Comment: Hmm. I understand that now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A router can only forward connections if it's able to *receive* the connections in the first place. Unfortunately, in your case, the ZTE router cannot receive any incoming connections because it is *itself* behind yet another NAT gateway – your ISP.

Note how the ZTE router's status screen does not show your public IP address anywhere – instead it shows a private-range address. This almost always means that "your" public IP address is actually shared between multiple customers through NAT.

The traceroute loop is another sure sign that the public IP address isn't even assigned to any physical device. Most likely the ISP's NAT gateway has a whole address range routed to it, and doesn't actually have any specific routes for it, relying entirely on its NAT table to magically intercept those addresses. (If a packet doesn't match the NAT table it still follows the default route and gets sent back whence it came, resulting in a loop.)

Overall, this is not something that you could fix through technical means. You can only call your ISP and ask for a dedicated IP address (which they might charge extra for, assuming they bother to provide one at all).

Your only other option is to rent a server at some hosting company (a VPS will do) and set up a VPN server there. Then configure your home router to connect *out* to the hosted VPN server, and you'll be able to use that active tunnel to reach your home LAN from within the server and from any device connected to the same VPN.